can't bundle rn project due to java & sdk mismatch
NOTE: I HAVE RN PROJECT WHITH LATEST UPDATES, SO FILES DIRECTORIES MAY DIFFER(
`
ENCOUTERING ERROR WHEN BUILDING APP:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-bluetooth-serial-next:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease'.


Could not create task ':react-native-bluetooth-serial-next:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installRelease -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-bluetooth-serial-next:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease'. > Could not create task ':react-native-bluetooth-serial-next:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above * Try: >
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1m.
Tried to update java & sdk versions to lts using android studio, code writed in vs code.
also in android studio downloaded all useful and unuseful plugins up to latest versions
regarding to PATH environment, i checked all ways and they seem to be OK
i have latest versions of node js and almost all installed libraries that found
Don't know what else can I check`

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think, this will not work, there is no need to update Java, Sdk or anything as these are already up to date as you mentioned in first line.
what you need to update is the library you are using, but react-native-bluetooth-serial-next is deprecated and not updated since 2019.
I will recommend you to use any different dependency from following

react-native-bluetooth-state-manager
react-native-ble-plx
react-native-ble-manager

